# Android app crash after swipe out from the recent list

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, swipe

My app is working properly but when I swipe it out from recent task list and run again this error occur.

```
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity      ComponentInfo{com.example.vaccinationsystem/com.example.vaccinationsystem.GenUserFunction}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.example.vaccinationsystem.GenUserFunction.Alerts(GenUserFunction.java:286)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.example.vaccinationsystem.GenUserFunction.onCreate(GenUserFunction.java:82)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-18 22:51:28.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

I'm doing it without swipe 0ut from recent list so it is working proper but after that it will crash.
My GenUserFunction:

```
package com.example.vaccinationsystem;


public class GenUserFunction extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button bVRC, bRC, bFB, bMap, bNews, bAlters;
TextView tvNotification;
String userId;
SoapObject request;
PropertyInfo p_userId;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
HttpTransportSE httpTransport;
SoapPrimitive response;
LinearLayout alertboxLayout;

int countNotification = 0;
int totalDifference;
ArrayList<String> listRec;
String s;
PendingIntent piService1;
Intent Service1;
AlarmManager alarmManager1;

private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Alerts";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://org.fyp.ws";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://org.fyp.ws/Alerts";
private static final String URL = StaticIP.ipAddress
        + "GeneralUserServices?wsdl";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // // full Screen
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.general_user);
    initialize();
    userId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("user_id");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    // stopService(new Intent(this, BackgroundServices.class));

    // Service1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,
    // BackgroundServices.class);
    // Service1.putExtra("user_Id", userId);
    // piService1 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext() , 0 ,
    // Service1 , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)
    // getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
    // alarmManager1.cancel(piService1);
    // alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP ,
    // System.currentTimeMillis() , 11000 , piService1);

    Alerts();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
    blowUp.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutUs:

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "About Us",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        break;
    case R.id.logout:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // stopService(new Intent(this, BackgroundServices.class));
        // alarmManager1.cancel(piService1);

        Editor editor = Splash.sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.remove("login_check");
        editor.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.LOGIN");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

        break;

    case R.id.exit:
        finish();

        break;
    }

    return false;
}

public void initialize() {
    bVRC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVRC);
    bRC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRC);
    bFB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFB);
    bMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMaps);
    bNews = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNews);
    bAlters = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAlerts);
    tvNotification = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNotification);
    // alertboxLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.abc);
    bVRC.setOnClickListener(this);
    bRC.setOnClickListener(this);
    bFB.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMap.setOnClickListener(this);
    bNews.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAlters.setOnClickListener(this);
    listRec = new ArrayList<String>();


    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    p_userId = new PropertyInfo();
    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bVRC:
        Intent intentVCR = new Intent(
                "android.intent.action.VIEWCHILDRECORD");
        intentVCR.putExtra("user_id", userId);
        startActivity(intentVCR);
        break;
    case R.id.bRC:
        Intent intentRC = new Intent("android.intent.action.REGCHILD");
        intentRC.putExtra("user_id", userId);
        startActivity(intentRC);

        break;
    case R.id.bFB:
        Intent intentFB = new Intent("android.intent.action.FEEDBACK");
        intentFB.putExtra("user_id", userId);
        startActivity(intentFB);

        break;
    case R.id.bMaps:

        Intent intentMap = new Intent(
                "android.intent.action.VACCINATIONMAP");
        intentMap.putExtra("user_id", userId);
        startActivity(intentMap);

        break;
    case R.id.bNews:

        Intent intentNews = new Intent("android.intent.action.NEWSRECORD");
        intentNews.putExtra("user_id", userId);
        startActivity(intentNews);
        break;
    case R.id.bAlerts:

        customDialogbox a = new customDialogbox(GenUserFunction.this,
                listRec);
        a.show();

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void Alerts() {
    p_userId.setName("userId");// Define the variable name in the web
    p_userId.setValue(userId);// Define value for fname variable
    p_userId.setType(String.class);// Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(p_userId);// Pass properties to the variable

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    try {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(),
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String[] row = response.toString().split("`");

        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {

            String[] record = row[i].split("~");
            // totalDifference = 0;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            String curDate = df.format(c.getTime()).toString();
            String visitDate = record[1];

            java.util.Date cD = df.parse(curDate);
            java.util.Date vD = df.parse(visitDate);

            Calendar cCurDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            cCurDate.setTime(cD);
            cCurDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);
            java.util.Date newCurDate = cCurDate.getTime();

            Calendar cNotificationStartVisitDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            cNotificationStartVisitDate.setTime(vD);
            cNotificationStartVisitDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -15);
            java.util.Date notificationStartDate = cNotificationStartVisitDate
                    .getTime();

            Calendar cOrignalVisitDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            cOrignalVisitDate.setTime(vD);
            cOrignalVisitDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);
            java.util.Date newOriDateVisitDate = cOrignalVisitDate
                    .getTime();
            totalDifference = 0;

            if (notificationStartDate.before(newCurDate)) {

                while (newOriDateVisitDate.after(newCurDate)) {
                    cOrignalVisitDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
                    newOriDateVisitDate = cOrignalVisitDate.getTime();
                    totalDifference++;
                    s = "left";
                }
                while (newOriDateVisitDate.before(newCurDate)) {
                    cOrignalVisitDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, +1);
                    newOriDateVisitDate = cOrignalVisitDate.getTime();
                    totalDifference++;
                    s = "ago";
                }
                countNotification++;
                listRec.add(row[i] + "~" + String.valueOf(totalDifference)
                        + "~" + s);

            }

        }
        if (countNotification > 0) {

            tvNotification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotification.setText(String.valueOf(countNotification));

        }

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // String.valueOf(listRec.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

}


  }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `GenUserFunction`, specifically lines 298 and 286?

Comment: Post ur code. U have errors due to not trying and catching null things. 286,298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess and strongly believe the error is in `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Just replace that with only `e.printStackTrace()` ....

This is my guess.... If not just post here or mark in the code which is line number 286 ?

thx

Comment: Due to this my app is not crashing anymore but you can see the soap services I'm using, Data is not coming from server after running.

Comment: the error you first posted is fixed or not ?

Just see the generated message in e.printStackTrace() if any...

Comment: Now there is a problem in Alerts() method. Can you tell my why it is going in catch body?

Comment: for that you will need to post here the catch method message the stack or the message being printed error can be for any reason .. nullpointer , internet connection , missing manifest permission , missing page on server etc.. etc... so until one does not see the catch method exception how can i say !!!!  hope you got my point...

Comment: Could I show you my error again?

Comment: That error is fixed now u will have another log plz recheck and see...

Comment: if its not fixed yes i expected the generated log would be different since the error has changed so update the message...

Comment: App is working properly. Services do its task perfect but if i will remove from recent list then in settings -> running app -> 0 process and 1 service and in a second it shows restarting but app got crash.